# How to create ggplot with facet_grid() for each column of a matrix

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I want to create a plot in R with `ggplot()` to visualise the data included in variable `matrix` that looks like this:

```
matrix <- matrix(c(time =c(1,2,3,4,5),v1=rnorm(5),v2=c(NA,1,0.5,0,0.1)),nrow=5)
colnames(matrix) <- c("time","v1","v2")

df <-data.frame(
  time=rep(matrix[,1],2),
  values=c(matrix[,2],matrix[,3]),
  names=rep(c("v1","v2"), each=length(matrix[,1]))
)
ggplot(df, aes(x=time,y=values,color=names)) +
  geom_point()+
  facet_grid(names~.)
```

Is there a faster way than transforming the data in a data.frame like I do? This way seems to be very laborious..
I would appreciate every help!! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tidyverse approach:

This will produce the data structure you need to use in ggplot

```
library(tidyverse)
 matrix %>% 
  as_data_frame() %>% 
  gather(., names, value, -time)
```

This will generate data structure and plot all at once

```
matrix %>% 
  as_data_frame() %>% 
  gather(., names, value, -time) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x=time,y=value,color=names)) + 
  geom_point()+
  facet_grid(names~.)
```